# Does Database have PATCH?

Tags: database, patch, put

Recently am working Database (SQL) . And we have enabled GET,GET/{ID},POST/ PUT[{ID} Operations for client.

**Client came up and asking what about Patch !!!**

I know the diff b/w Put and Patch. you want to update with whole payload or just few fields .

GET-SELECT

POST-INSERT

PUT-UPDATE

**PATCH- ?**

FYI: my api PUT/{ID} works even with whole payload or small payload.

Answer (score 0):

In true senseof the word, both PUT and PATCH point to a DB UPDATE operation.Since you're already aware of differences b/w PUT/PATCH and your API PUT/{ID} is able to handle whole/partial update, there's practically no point in having another PATCH method(unless it pleases your client! :) ).